# Use path based routing instead of sub domain in nginx

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, routing

I am trying to perform a path based routing instead of subdomain to serve the built folder of react application. The nginx configration to serve the static files in the built folder is:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/Project/build;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name web.example.com;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri /index.html;
        }
}
```

Currently it is served in **web.domain.xyz** but I want something like **domain.xyz/web**

I took reference of [this documentation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/) and did something like this to serve the index.html file created in build folder

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/project/build;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name example.com;

        location /web {
                try_files $uri $uri /index.html;
        }
}
```

Comment: Your question is somewhat confusing. Twice you use the term "something like". If you provided examples of URLs and the corresponding filesystem locations then maybe we might understand what you are trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 1):

The pitfall with `root` directive is that the URI is appended after it when requests are resolved.

In your case, when request is made to `http://www.example.com/web/`, nginx tries to find `/var/www/project/build/web/index.html` to satisfy the request.

If you want to store your files in `build` and not in `build/web`, you need to use `alias` directive:

```
location /web {
    alias /var/www/project/build;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```